# Database connection pooling datastructure

Tags: java, database, algorithm, data-structures

I would like to develop database connection pooling.

Could anyone please tell me about which data structure need to use to maintain the pool ?

Comment: Instead of developing your own why not use a library like [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) that is widely used and well tested.

Comment: Also, apache licensing works wonders for almost all kind of projects.

Answer (score 10):

It should be implemented using **Object Pool desing pattern**. You can read about it in 
[Kircher, Michael; Prashant Jain; (2002-07-04). "Pooling Pattern". EuroPLoP 2002. Retrieved on 2007-06-09.](http://www.kircher-schwanninger.de/michael/publications/Pooling.pdf) or in [Object Pool Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool). Java implementation for `ObjectPool` and `JDBCConnectionPool` classes can be found [here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool/java).

Object Pool is usually a **singleton** with **two collections** of objects (e.g. database connections) inside:

1. **unlocked** - for free objects, which can be provided to the client by request
2. **locked** - for locked objects, which are in use now

This collections can be implemented as `Lists` or `HashTables` or something else, depends on your needs. For simple ObjectPool - **`LinkedList`** structure will be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-1998/jw-06-object-pool.html. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You generally need:

- some kind of wrapper around the "raw" Connection objects to manage things like when the connection was last given out, diagnostic information, possibly a cache of your prepared statements for that connection etc-- you define this to include what you need
- a collection to put the connection wrappers in that supports concurrent additions/removals-- any properly synchronized list would do, but a ConcurrentLinkedQueue would be a reasonable choice
- a way to manage allocations from the pool-- consider using the [Semaphore](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_semaphore.shtml) class
- possibly, grouping various pools togther into some "pool management class" (e.g. so you can just call "getConnection(databaseName, readOnly)" and it goes to the relevant pool)

On top of this, you can then build whatever logging/monitoring you require.

There are also advocates for off-the-shelf connection pool frameworks. I know there are those who disagree, but I personally wouldn't go down this route-- a connection pool (a) really isn't difficult to write, (b) forms a key part of your system that you probably need to understand and customise.

Answer (score 0):

Is an open source solution what you're looking for?

See [Apache Database Connection Pool API](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/package-summary.html#package_description)

Comment: I don't think there's a specific data structure to be used in the object pool design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool

An object pool's backing store might be something as simple as an array - it's how you manage access to a limited number of resources by a undefined number of resource users that defines the aspects of an object pool.

Comment: @diciu -  Mentioned link is broken... Can u update it?

Answer (score 0):

See this Sun Developer Tutorial: [Connection Pooling](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html):

> In releases prior to JDBC 2.0 every
>   database session requires a new
>   connection and login even if the
>   previous connection and login used the
>   same table and user account. If you
>   are using a JDBC release prior to 2.0
>   and want to improve performance, you
>   can cache JDBC connections instead.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it's wise to create your own.

I've used [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0) connection pooling (with [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/)) across many projects with great success